# adding white-spaces between multiple outputs of XML::xmlValue() in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing, whitespace, space

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
raw <- GET("http://hse.ru/org/persons",
           query = list(udept = "135083"))
raw_text <- content(raw, "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
parsed <- htmlParse(raw_text)
interests <- xpathSApply(parsed, 
                        '/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div', 
                         xmlValue)
interests[31:32]
[1] "прикладная эконометрикаЭмпирический анализ рынков(…)"
[2] "современная теория правасоциология права"
```

For those who are not familiar with Russian. The last two lines can hardly be interpreted as:

```
interests[31:32]
[1] "applied econometricsEmpirical analysis of markets"
[2] "modern legal theorysociology of law"
```

The objects to which I'm applying `xmlValue` have this kind of structure (translated):

```
[[1]]
<div class="with-indent small">
  <a class="tag" href="/org/persons/?intst=62024792">applied econometrics</a>
  <a class="tag" href="/org/persons/?intst=62247389">empirical analysis of markets</a>
  (...)
</div> 

[[2]]
<div class="with-indent small">
  <a class="tag" href="/org/persons/?intst=132077027">modern legal theory</a>
  (...)
  <a class="tag" href="/org/persons/?intst=52953762">sociology of law</a>
</div>
```

I'm wondering how can I add the white-space (or `"; "`) as a separator between the values and obtain the following:

```
 interests[31:32]
 [1] "applied econometrics Empirical analysis of markets"
 [2] "modern legal theory sociology of law"
```

---

I've tried to use the `xmlValue` with `paste` (`xpathSApply(parsed, 'pattern', paste(xmlValue, " "))`) and received an error.

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: @Ouistiti `Error in paste(xmlValue, " ") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right (can't read Russian), you can use `getChildrenStrings`:

```
sapply(parsed['/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div', fun = getChildrenStrings], paste, collapse = ";")
# ...
# [30] "экономика образования;мониторинг образования;качество образования;оплата труда;06.71.45 Экономика образования"                                                                                                                                                                    
# [31] "прикладная эконометрика;Эмпирический анализ рынков;Количественные маркетинговые исследования;прикладная статистика;06.00.00 Экономика. Экономические науки"                                                                                                                    
# [32] "современная теория права;чистое учение о праве;проблемы суверенитета;социология права" 
# ...
```

Comment: Definitely faster too.